# Inline signing with bind 9.9 and NSEC3

Tags: bind, dnssec

Since version 9.9, Bind supports [inline signing](https://deepthought.isc.org/article/AA-00626/109/Inline-Signing-in-ISC-BIND-9.9.0-Examples.html), but I don't find any information on how to make it working with NSEC3. I cannot add NSEC3PARAM RR with nsupdate : I think it's normal because of inline signing, but I cannot parameter this for inline signing.

Has someone setup and tested it, or an idea ?

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer on bind-user mailing list.

Instead of using nsupdate, I should use the next command :

```
rndc signing -nsec3param 1 1 100 $(head -c 512 /dev/random | sha1sum | cut -b 1-16) <zonename>
```

Hope this question will help someone in the future.